# Admob in Dreamweaver Phonegap build app?

Tags: admob, dreamweaver

I've done an app with Dreamweaver CS6 for android, using phonegap. I don't know how to integrate admob in that app. Anybody know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need eclipse to add admob